# SQL: CASE expression with declared variable

Tags: sql, sql-server, case, declare

I have following example that doesn't work in SQL server.
table1.field1 is also a char(3)

```
DECLARE @CALCULATED_FIELD char(3);

SELECT table1.field1
       ,table1.field2
       ,CASE 
            WHEN table1.field2 = '1' THEN @CALCULATED_FIELD = table1.field1
            ELSE @CALCULATED_FIELD = 'ALL'
       END
FROM table1
```

Anyone knows the problem with the case statement?

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: for the @CALCULATED_FIELD, what do you need to be returned?

Comment: Also a case expression returns a singleton. It can't be used for logic flow like an `IF` statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The result of the `CASE` expression must be assigned to the variable, but it is not allowed in the same statement to return any columns from the table.
So this:

```
SELECT  
  @CALCULATED_FIELD = CASE 
    WHEN field2 = '1' THEN field1 
    ELSE 'ALL' 
  END 
FROM table1
```

is syntactically valid, although it will assign to the variable finally, the result of the `CASE` expression of the last row fetched.

By the name of the variable, I suspect that you want a 3d column which will be *calculated* by `CASE`:

```
SELECT field1, field2, 
  CASE 
    WHEN field2 = '1' THEN field1 
    ELSE 'ALL' 
  END calculated_field
FROM table1
```

See a simplified [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=0c7e76d2009006e1bae0d067df9eb871).

Answer (score 1):

A SQL Server `SELECT` statement can *either* assign variable values or return rows, but not both.  You might intend:

```
SELECT @CALCULATED_FIELD = COALESCE(table1.field1, 'ALL')
FROM table1;
```

This would assign the maximum value to the variable -- and the only value if the table has only one row.  If the table has no rows, the variable would be assigned `'ALL'`.

Comment: I don't understand the relevance of COALESCE() with this requirement.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a scaler funtion in this case

```
CREATE FUNCTION calcfield
  (
   @field2 VARCHAR(4),
   @field1 VARCHAR(4)
   )  
  RETURNS VARCHAR(3)
   AS
   BEGIN
   DECLARE @CalcField CHAR(3)
   SELECT @CalcField = CASE 
       WHEN @field2 = '1' THEN  @field1
        ELSE  'ALL'
    END 
   RETURN @CalcField
  END
 GO
```

and then change your query to

```
  SELECT table1.field1
   ,table1.field2
   ,dbo.calcfield(table1.field2,table1.field1) 
  FROM table1
```

Answer (score 0):

Expressions like `A=B` is not a scalar value. So when you run the following query, it fails and you will get an error `Incorrect syntax near '='`.

```
SELECT ('aaa' = 'aaa')
```

In your case

```
CASE WHEN table1.field2 = '1'
THEN @CALCULATED_FIELD = table1.field1
ELSE @CALCULATED_FIELD = 'ALL'
END
```

is not a valid expression, and you might mean something like

```
CASE WHEN table1.field2 = '1'
THEN (CASE WHEN @CALCULATED_FIELD = table1.field1 THEN 1 ELSE 0)
ELSE (CASE WHEN @CALCULATED_FIELD = 'ALL' THEN 1 ELSE 0)
END
```

Please note that you can run a query like

```
SELECT columnName = 'aaa'
```

and it works as

```
SELECT 'aaa' AS columnName
```

Answer (score 0):

Thx a lot.
For the create function, I have no rights and we can't do it on the production environment. But would work. Nice.

The example from forpas used and it works perfect for me.